# how to prin a message in screen and then redirect to other page php/js

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a form and i connected with php to a database.It works perfect but i 'd like to show me o pop up message that is succesfull login .

```
<form id = "quiz" name="quiz" method="post" action="insert.php" >
name: <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="π.χ. George" required="">

<label for="name"> </label>
faculty: <input type="text" name="faculty" placeholder="Enter your Faculty" required="">

<input class="btn btn-one" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

insert.php is the php file that connect the form fields with the database.
then try this in this file:

```
echo "<script>alert('message successfully sent');</script>";
header('Location: main.html');
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

but i get an error.If i delete echo "alert('message successfully sent');"; works perfect but i would like to have a message that's successfull.

Comment: You can not send output to the client _and_ redirect elsewhere at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
  echo "<script>alert('message successfully sent');
    window.location.href='main.html'

    </script>";
```